# backbonejs node file upload

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, upload

None of the answers I have found anywhere have worked. I am trying to extend the example in "Developing Backbone.js Applications" to upload files. Although the form has enctype="multipart/form-data," request.files is always undefined.

The form HTML is:

```
<form id="addBook" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="coverImage">CoverImage: </label><input id="coverImage" name="coverImage" type="file" />
        <label for="title">Title: </label><input id="title" type="text" />
        <label for="author">Author: </label><input id="author" type="text" />
        <label for="releaseDate">Release date: </label><input id="releaseDate" type="text" />
        <label for="keywords">Keywords: </label><input id="keywords" type="text" />
        <button id="add">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The backbone that saves the new record is

```
  addBook: function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {};
    var reader = new FileReader();
    $( '#addBook div' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
        if( $( el ).val() != '' )
        {
            if( el.id === 'keywords' ) {
                formData[ el.id ] = [];
                _.each( $( el ).val().split( ' ' ), function( keyword ) {
                    formData[ el.id ].push({ 'keyword': keyword });
                });
            } else if( el.id === 'releaseDate' ) {
                formData[ el.id ] = $( '#releaseDate' ).datepicker( 'getDate' ).getTime();
            } else {
                formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
            }
        }
    });
        console.log(formData);
        this.collection.create( formData );
    }
```

The Node being called.

```
//Insert a new book
app.post( '/api/books', function( request, response ) {
    console.log(request.body);
    console.log(request.files);
});
```

The value of coverimage send to node is correct, I just never get anything in request.files. I have a cool drag and drop I would like to use instead, but until I get this working I am stuck.

I tried the JQuery-file-upload, that got me nowhere.

If I had hair, I would be pulling it out right now.

Comment: http://estebanpastorino.com/2013/09/27/simple-file-uploads-with-backbone-dot-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also following the sample of the book "Developing Backbone.js Applications", I extended the functionality to upload images to a folder in the server and save the path in my model to show the correct images. It is working fine. I tried to use Plupload and other jquery plugins but I didn't like them. My sample is using ajax to upload images to the server and then using them. I read many posts referencing the use of iframes to have ajax functionality. The best approach for this I found is using the jquery.form.js to avoid postbacks and load the images in a nice way.

The running sample working fine with nodeJS:

https://github.com/albertomontellano/bookLibrarySampleNodeJS

I based my solution in the post of Mark Dawson:

http://markdawson.tumblr.com/post/18359176420/asynchronous-file-uploading-using-express-and-node-js

However, I had to correct a method of this post to make it work correctly:

```
app.post('/api/photos', function(req, res) {
var responseServerPath = 'images/' + req.files.userPhoto.name;
var serverPath = 'site/images/' + req.files.userPhoto.name;
console.log(req.files.userPhoto.path);
require('fs').rename(
    req.files.userPhoto.path,
    serverPath,
    function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send({
                error: 'Ah crap! Something bad happened'
            });
            return;
        }

        res.send({
            path: responseServerPath
        });
    }
);
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be submitting the file as part of the `model.save`/`collection.create(model)`.

What I've used is [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for a file upload manager, submitting a file to an upload handler.  This upload handler either returns the path to the uploaded file, or fileId if a reference is stored in a database table.

From there I populate a property in my backbone model, then persist the model.  You can have your model `listenTo` plupload, for an upload completed event or similar.

Comment: I am very new to backbone, I can't figure out at all how to get started. Do you have any simple examples? I just need the basic example, with a single file upload. I can figure out the listeners later, but I just can't get the upload buttons to work one the page with the backbone, and I don't know how to upload the file when the user clicks upload.

Comment: There is no "Basic" example I can provide, as I don't believe your file upload should happen via a typical backbone sync.  My suggestion is for you to develop something to upload a file, then setting a reference to that file on your book model, then syncing the file.  You seem to have no trouble getting your model to your back-end, so your issue is with uploading.  As for how to combine the file and the model, I've explained how I've done it previously.

Comment: That's why I started this thread, to figure out how to get the file uploaded. I haven't been able to make any headway on how to do that through backbone at all. I was hoping for help on that part, sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score -2):

Turned out I had to end up hiring someone to do it, because I can't find any examples online of anybody uploading a file through backbone, even without updating any database interaction. Everybody has the same basic advice about what tools to use to upload the files, but I can't for the life of me find ONE example of someone implementing it.

I am planning on making the code available to everybody, so they can see how it works.

Comment: This example isn't an example of uploading a file through backbone, which is what your question asked for.  This is an example of uploading a file via JavaScript.